# Problems accessing Web Service using Parallels (OSX, Win 7)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, macos, parallels

I am currently running Windows 7 through Parallels on my Mac(mountain lion). I developed a web service using Visual Studios 2010. I am able to access the web service when I "Start program without debugging" but I still can't access the web service through another web browser (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

Here is what I have done so far:

- At first I thought it was something wrong with my network connection between OSX and Win 7 so I bridged the network through airport between OSX and Win 7. But for some reason the IP addresses are still different MAC (192.168.1.121) WIN 7(192.168.1.131). So I guess this could still be the problem.
- The next thing I did was changed how Visual Studios starts the program from Visual Studio Development Server to Local IIS Server as was suggested through something that I found on the internet.

So my question is how can I access the webservice through another web browser using parallels?

Comment: *But for some reason the IP addresses are still different* If you've bridged the virtual adapter to your physical adapter and there's a router somewhere doing DHCP, this is what I'd expect.

Comment: But would the VM and OSX having different IP Address affect the fact that I can't access the web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for some reason the IP addresses are still different MAC (192.168.1.121) WIN 7(192.168.1.131)

Yes, it is supposed to be so, because they are different machines and have to have different IPs

1. Do you able to access the service from browser started in the same VM using address 127.0.0.1?
2. If yes, do you able to access it from Mac using IP-address of Win7?

If 2 fails, then you should try to disable Firewall in Win7 VM, most likely it blocks access to service.